# Can't send emails! - SmtpFailedRecipientException: failed recipients - C# - Unity - Gmail

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gmail

I am having problems with sending emails from unity with gmail. It used to work before, but now it doesn't.

Here is my code (there are some dutch words in it as message):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress("hotkeycode@gmail.com", "Team HotkeyCode");
    mail.To.Add(CEmail);
    mail.Subject = "Bevestigings code voor de verlofuren bijhouder";
    mail.Body = "Hier heeft u uw bevestigingscode voor de verlofuren bijhouder: \n \n" + ConfirmCode + "\n \nBedankt voor het gebruiken van de verlofurenbijhouder! \n \nMet vriendelijke groet,\nTeam HotkeyCode\n\nHeeft u deze aanvraag niet gedaan? Negeer dit bericht dan en verwijder het!";

    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    smtpServer.Port = 587;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("hotkeycode@gmail.com", "CENCORED PASSWORD") as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };
    smtpServer.Send(mail);
```

I don't know what is going wrong. Please help me!

Thanks in advance,

Ablos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

After a long time searching and debugging, I found that the variable 'CEmail' was empty! So the code had no email to send the mail to. This was a very stupid mistake, if you have the same problem, please debug all of the variables to see if they are filled in!

-Ablos

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to set a low security in your gmail account 
in this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

Comment: You need some glasses. He had that `SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;`. Look at his question again. You are correct about the google security stuff. Last time I check, you had to make settings to allow your email to work with un-known apps or something similar for it to work.

Comment: You're right, this is my first answer and I'm a little confused .. i fixed it

Comment: That's fine.+1 Welocme to SO.

Comment: Well I have that enabled, first it didn't work. I followed every step from GOOGLE to get rid of the security things that might be blocking unity. When I did that it worked, but today it suddenly stopped working...